# Where can I get C/C++ sample code for merge sort a link list?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, list, sorting

Where can I get a sample code for merge sort a link list?

Comment: singly-linked or doubly-linked list?

Comment: This should be tagged as homework !

Answer (score 3):

[Here.](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.c) (Courtesy of [Google](http://google.com/))

Comment: This was for doubly link list : struct element { element *next, *prev;
    int i;};

Answer (score 3):

Here's [a description of how to implement it](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/algorithms/listsort.html).